# What happens if I pull a change on a file earlier set assume-unchanged in Git?

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

I'm curious if I run `git update-index --assume-unchanged`, and somebody chages that file in a way that produces a conflict, what happens, if I pull those changes? Do I get a simple conflict? Does it overwrite my changes, since it assumes the file is not changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy to test. With Git 1.9.1 on my Linux machine, Git detects that such changes would be lost and prevents that from happening:

```
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From file:///XXXXXXX
   493134f..d04cb06  master     -> origin/master
Updating 493134f..d04cb06
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        foo.bar
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

As a side note, I recommend avoiding `git update-index` if you can, as it [was not designed with end users in mind](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain).

Comment: Very good answer, I like your note at the end. I also use it very few, and only when I use Git in combination of bad team cooperation and SVN. :D